# Custom Dialog in android

Tags: android

I want to custom dialog to change only body of the alert. I want to output like in this screen shot:

[image]

But I have no idea on such a type of dialog. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did U go thru this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Comment: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-alertdialog-your-android-application Hope this helps , you can set what ever button you want by `setPositiveButton` and `setNegativeButton`

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10783191/1289716

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below link

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application

http://www.thiyagaraaj.com/articles/android-articles/customdialogboxpopupusinglayoutinandroid

http://www.thecompboy.com/2011/11/android-tutorial-custom-dialog.html

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/06/android-custom-dialog-box-sample-code.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can change your Dialog box as you want.You can do this by creating a custom dialog box. Step1.Create a style in String file in res

```
 <style name="myQuitDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog"> 
   <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>

    </style>
```

Step2. Create the xml file in layouts

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_quit"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/image which u want to show"
 >
```

Step3. Write code of custom dialog box in src

```
 class Custom_Dialog extends Dialog {

        protected Custom_Dialog(Context context, int theme) {
            super(context, theme);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    }
private void show_alert() {
        final Custom_Dialog alertbox = new Custom_Dialog(this, R.style.myQuitDialog);
        Window window = alertbox.getWindow();
        window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        window.requestFeature(window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        alertbox.show(); 
        alertbox.setCancelable(true);
        alertbox.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);


                 alertbox.dismiss();
            }



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make your own activity and set `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` property for it in AndroidManifest.xml so it'll looks like dialog-window

Comment: what do you need to be explained? how to build similar window in .xml?
if you are asking about showing this dialog it's similar to starting new simple activity - the only difference than it'll be shown in dialog-window