# how to catch an exception and modify with an error custom dialog

Tags: android, android-layout

i have already this exception in my app but i want to create a custom dialog
heres my exception:

```
10-11 01:41:49.420: E/AACPlayer(649): playAsync():
10-11 01:41:49.420: E/AACPlayer(649): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Cannot start native decoder
```

and instead of show this **java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot start native decoder** to person, show like Error!! stream is down.

i tried something like this:

```
 try
        {
            aacPlayer.playAsync( getUrl());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error in radio");
            alertDialog.setMessage("out of service");
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  // here you can add functions
               }
            });
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

but without luck it doesnt shows the custom dialog what can recommend me for this?

thanks very much.

Comment: Do you want to create a custom dialog ??

Comment: yeah i dont know if its possible ? so people doesnt see that java.lang.runtime dialog instead they see a custom error dialog, or cant be possible? thanks

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784504/custom-dialog-in-android/10784657#10784657

Comment: Will it work if the there is a custom message in the dialog that already pops up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See it, maybe it can help you ;)

[How to catch a 'java.lang.RuntimeException'](http://eai.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/seebeyond-l/how-to-catch-a-javalangruntimeexception-370493) or [Throwing and Catching Exceptions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Throwing_and_Catching_Exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

Will it work if the there is a custom message in the dialog that already pops up? If yes then you may want to do this in your catch block:

```
CustomException ce = new CustomException();
throw ce;
```

And have a custom exception like this

```
public static class CustomException extends Exception {

    String errorMsg; // this is the string that the your alert box will show

    public CustomException() {
        super();
        errorMsg = "YOU DID THIS ALL"; // set string here for your custom message
    }

    public CustomException(String err) { // set custom string in the constructor itself
        super(err);
        errorMsg = err;
    }

    public String getError() {
        return errorMsg;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return errorMsg;
    }
}
```